# Error al llamar Módulo en Tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de usar módulos en mi programa, pero al hacer la llamada, me genera un error y no encuentro donde o como resolverlo.

Aquí creo importo modulo_password como mp

```
import random
import winsound
import time

import modulo_password as mp

#creo mi clase
class Juego_Principal:

    db_name = 'database_carale.db'
    #Constructor    
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.sw_pre='True'

         # Se crea una ventana principal
         self.wind = window
         self.wind.title('Aplicacion tipo Juego CARALE Ver 1.0p')
         self.wind.resizable(width=False, height=False)
         self.wind.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

Acá llamo al modulo que importe

```
def modulo_clave(self):
    mp.cuadro_pregunta()
    return
```

En el módulo o archivo modulo_password.py tengo el siguiente código

```
from tkinter import *

#Se crea una clase password preguntas
class password_preguntas:
#Se inicializamos la clase

    def __init__(self, window):
        def cuadro_pregunta():
            wind_password = Toplevel()
            wind_password.title('Introduzca Password')
            wind_password.geometry("252x150+530+200")
            wind_password.resizable(width=False, height=False)

            user_name = StringVar()  # User name variable
            password = StringVar()  # Password variable

            # creating an entry widget to take usuario


        def show_password(self):
            print("User Name is", user_name.get())
           print("Password is", password.get())

        # defining function to clear entry widgets using .set() method
        def clear(self):
            user_name.set("")
            password.set("")
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa, me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy tratando de usar módulos para organizar mi programa y hacer mas fácil la lectura del mismo, he revisado y leído pero no entiendo porque me genera este error, su me pueden ayudar, por favor.

Comment: tienes que llamar al objeto, no una funcion del objeto... sería primero password_preguntas y luego cuadro_pregunta. Si necesitas mayor ayuda te puedo dejar una respuesta

Comment: por favor, te lo agradecería, porque creo estar haciéndolo así, y me sigue generando error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes, en tu módulo `modulo_password.py` es que todas las funciones las tienes definidas dentro del `__init__(self)`, es decir, al momento de crear el objeto (no son funciones del objeto, una vez lo creas desaparecen, a menos que las uses dentro del `__init__`). Por lo que sería cosa de moverlas un nivel de indentación más atrás.

```
class password_preguntas:

    def __init__(self, window):
        pass # no sé que quieres hacer acá

    def cuadro_pregunta(self):
        wind_password = Toplevel()
        wind_password.title('Introduzca Password')
        wind_password.geometry("252x150+530+200")
        wind_password.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        user_name = StringVar()  # User name variable
        password = StringVar()  # Password variable

        # creating an entry widget to take usuario


    def show_password(self):
        print("User Name is", user_name.get())
        print("Password is", password.get())

    # defining function to clear entry widgets using .set() method
    def clear(self):
        user_name.set("")
        password.set("")
```

Una vez arreglado esto, también hay que modificar cómo llamamos a la clase `password_preguntas`. Estás intentando llamar directamente a `cuadro_pregunta()`, pero esto se encuentra dentro de tu clase, por lo que si no instancias la clase, no tienes forma de acceder a la función:

```
def modulo_clave(self):
    obj_clave = mp.password_preguntas(self.wind)
    obj_clave.cuadro_pregunta()
```

Creo que hay un par de problemas más con tu arquitectura, pero probablemente se debe a que no copiaste todo el código, o aún estás aprendiendo, por ejemplo, no necesitarías pasarle la ventana `window` a tu `password_preguntas`, dado que usas un Toplevel...

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, funciono tus consejos, muy agradecido, estoy aprendiendo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que con la sentencia `mp.cuadro_pregunta()` se espera que dentro del archivo `modulo_password.py` exista una función llamada `cuadro_pregunta()`. Por lo que veo en tu archivo `modulo_password.py` solo existe una clase, no existe una función llamada `cuadro_pregunta()`, entonces está intentando importar algo que no existe.

**¿Cuál es la manera correcta de importar cosas?**

En Python se pueden importar variables, funciones y clases (también objetos, pero los objetos en sí están almacenados dentro de una variable). Hagamos un intento de importación:

Tengo una carpeta llamada "Mi proyecto", en esa tengo un archivo .py en el que voy a trabajar y otra archivo llamado "modulo.py" donde tengo unas funciones que voy a usar. **Ambos archivos en el mismo directorio**:

```
Carpeta: Mi Proyecto
    Archivo: main.py
    Archivo: modulo.py
```

El contenido del archivo `modulo.py` es este:

```
def suma(a,b):
    return a + b

def saludos(nombre):
    return f"Hola {nombre}!"
```

Y en `main.py` importa la función `suma()`:

```
from modulo import suma

print(suma(3,3))
```

Hay que notar la manera en que se está importando, **estoy importando única y exclusivamente la función suma.** Por lo tanto si intento invocar a `saludos()`:

```
print(saludos("Juan Carlos"))
```

Obtendré un error:

```
NameError: name 'saludo' is not defined
```

Puedo importar varias cosas en específico del mismo modulo:

```
from modulo import suma,saludo #Esto solucionaría el problema anterior
```

**Otros selectores de importación:**

En vez de importar cosas en específico, también se puede importar todo el módulo. Para ejemplificar esto voy a añadir dos lineas a `modulo.py`:

```
color = "Azul"
numero_decimal = 3.664
```

Voy a usar estas variables en `main.py`, pero primero debo de cambiar la manera en que importo:

```
import modulo

print(modulo.suma(modulo.numero_decimal,3))
print(f"Mi color favorito es {modulo.color}")
```

Aquí usamos la importación `import modulo`, esto implica que tenemos que referirnos a cada elemento con la palabra modulo, seguido un punto y el elemento en cuestión.

En este ejemplo se hace uso de la función `suma()` definida dentro de `modulo.py`, por lo mismo en `main.py` se invoca así: `modulo.suma()`. De igual manera nos referimos a las variables definidas en `modulo.py`.

También hay que decir que escribir "modulo" cada vez que queramos usar algo es algo tedioso y ensucia el código, siempre podemos abreviar esa palabra:

```
import modulo as md
```

Ahora, por ejemplo, nos podríamos referir a `color` en `main.py` como `md.color`.

**El selector `*`:**

Este selector importa **absolutamente todo** del modulo en cuestión, por lo tanto no es necesario usar el nombre del módulo para referirse a un elemento de dicho módulo. Sin embargo, no siempre puede ser bueno esto, veamos un ejemplo:

Añadimos una estructura de control de flujo a `modulo.pý`, sin estar dentro de una función.

```
for i in range(3):
    print("Soy una estructura de control de flujo")
```

Si en `main.py` importamos a `modulo.py` de esta manera: `from modulo import *`. Podemos obtener resultados no deseados (depende de la intención con que lo hagas):

```
from modulo import *

print(f"Mi color favorito es {color}")
```

Devuelve:

```
Soy una estructura de control de flujo
Soy una estructura de control de flujo
Soy una estructura de control de flujo
Mi color favorito es Azul
```

Como digo, literalmente se importa **todo!**

**Importando clases y objetos dentro de una variable, e importaciones anidadas**

También es válido importar módulos que importen otro modulo, al igual que importar clases y objetos. Un ejemplo de esto:

Vamos a cambiar por completo el contenido de `modulo.py`:

```
import functools

class SuperNumero():
    def __init__(self,lista):
        self.lista = lista

    def generar_numero(self):
        return functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,self.lista)

numero1 = SuperNumero([1,2,3])
```

En este definimos una clase, una variable que almacena un objeto (generado por la clase) y importamos el modulo [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) de la [Librería Estándar de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/)

En `main.py` hacemos uso de estas cosas:

```
from modulo import numero1,SuperNumero

print(numero1.generar_numero())

numero2 = SuperNumero([4,5,6])
print(numero2.generar_numero())
```

Y obtenemos en ejecución esto:

```
6
15
```

**¿Qué podemos notar de esto?**

En `modulo.py`, en el método `generar_numero()` de la clase `SuperNumero` se hace uso de una función del módulo de `functools`. Por otro lado en `main.py` se hace uso de ese método y nos da el resultado esperado. Entonces pasó algo como esto:

```
main <= modulo <= functools
```

Es una importación válida, también se puede observar que se importo la clase `SuperNumero` y el objeto `numero1` sin problemas.

**¿Por qué tu importación no funciona?**

```
import modulo_password as mp
```

En esta sentencia se abrevia al nombre del modulo a mp, y se importan todos sus elementos **definidos**.

```
mp.cuadro_pregunta()
```

Invoca una **función** llamada `cuadro_pregunta()`, está no está definida como función dentro de `modulo_password.py`, a su vez está definido dentro de la clase `password_preguntas`.

**La solución:**

```
def modulo_clave(self):
    mp.password_preguntas.cuadro_pregunta()
    return
```

También hay que indentar bien la zona, hacer la definición del atributo `window` y su invocación correcta:

```
def __init__(self, window):
    self.wind_password = window

def cuadro_pregunta():
    self.wind_password = Toplevel()
    self.wind_password.title('Introduzca Password')
    self.wind_password.geometry("252x150+530+200")
    self.wind_password.resizable(width=False, height=False)
```

**Nota:** Clave aquí la palabra `self`, que hace referencia a la misma clase.

Espero te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Muy buena explicación , la verdad estoy aprendido y me a costado entender las clases y sus herencias, muy agradecido, saludos