# ¿Cómo utilizar funciones que uno define en Python?

Tags: python, librería, spyder

Tengo un archivo llamado 'Funciones' donde definí funciones y al querer usarlas en otro programa la terminal me arroja el siguiente error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Funciones'
```

¿Existe alguna manera de solucionarlo?.

Utilicé la siguiente sintaxis al querer llamar las funciones dentro del archivo.

```
from Funciones import Respuesta_S_N
```

Estuve buscando videos y la mayoría trabajaba con PyCharm donde el mismo programa les ayudaba a definir un módulo, sin embargo, mi ambiente de trabajo es Spyder a través de ANACONDA.

No tengo mucha experiencia al programar y estoy abierto a cualquier recomendación y ayuda.

Las especificaciones técnicas de mi ambiente de trabajo son las siguientes por si fuera necesario al momento de dar una solución.

*Sistema Operativo*: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

*Versión de Spyde*r: 4.0.1

Comment: Te sirve [mi respuesta en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373812/error-al-llamar-módulo-en-tkinter-python-3/373851#373851)?

Comment: Asegúrate que el archivo `Funciones.py` esté en el mismo directorio que el archivo donde estés trabajando.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, copié mi archivo 'Funciones.py' en la carpeta donde se encontraba mi programa donde trabajo. Pero esto me genera un conflicto, ¿siempre tengo que copiar este archivo en las carpetas donde se encuentren los programas que trabajo?.

Comment: Puedes usar definir la ruta de donde quieres importar por medio de un punto ("."): `from carpeta.subcarpeta.archivo import funcion`

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta te recuerdo que puedes puntuarla como positiva :3

Comment: Acabo de encontar [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087/cómo-importar-módulos-py-de-subcarpetas-a-carpetas), tal vez también te pueda servir.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios y con mucho gusto te pongo puntuación, sin embargo, la página no me deja puntuar comentarios, supongo que solo deja a respuestas.